# How to launch IE browser using selenium webdriver 3.4.0

Tags: selenium, webdriver

How to launch IE browser using selenium webdriver 3.4.0? I have tried, but unable to open an IE browser. I have downloaded IE Driver and followed the same like launching firefox driver.

Launching of Firefox browser is working fine, below are command lines

`System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\vidhya.r\\Desktop\\Automation\\Jars\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);`

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "Path of IE driver");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); use this

Answer (score 0):

Download [IEDriverServer](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.5/), put it to path or use

> System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", ieDriverPath);

launch via

```
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried the above, but it is throwing exception as, "java.lang.IllegalsStateException"

Comment: I got the same exception. I forgot to change from "webdriver.chrome.driver" to "webdriver.ie.driver" (in case  switch from chrome to ie)

Answer (score 0):

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capability.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);
capability.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR, 1); 
capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
capability.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);        

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", ieDriverPath);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capability);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually its opening 2 IE browsers. In first page it is dipslaying as "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server."                Second Page, it is connecting to url but not proceeding with the code

Comment: Confirm the IEDriver.exe is compatible with your IE browser. no matter your IE browser is 32/64 bit, please use IEDriver-32.exe. The 64 bit IEDriver is slow.

Answer (score 0):

First download IEDriver from this [Link](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.5/)

Use this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "Path of IE driver");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

If you want to add some capabilities then use `DesiredCapabilities`

Comment: Simple as you set path of geckodriver in similar way you can download IEdriver and set path in setproperty() and run

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried the above, but it is not connecting

Comment: "java.lang.IllegalsStateException"                                                                     IE Browser launch:               
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","driver path\\IEDriverServer.exe");WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();

Comment: Please paste what path you are giving where u store the IEdriver

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\vidhya.r\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe");                       
WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();

Comment: Replace the name of vidhya.r as vidhya_r in drive and in your code

Comment: try  to replace \\ with single forward slash / in path

Comment: That is my user id and I don't have permission to rename.

Comment: Ok try second comment

Comment: I have tried it is opening 2 IE browser page. in console got error like, "Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)". I think I have downloaded 32 bit instead of 64 bit.

Comment: Yes correct, Rest is fine. Seems you initilaize driver twice

Comment: Sorry to bother, after having 64 bit also, issue remains same, In IE browser, displaying as, "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver Server"

Comment: @BeforeTest
public void launch_Application() {     
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:/Users/vidhya.r/Documents/IEDriverServer.exe");
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("http://192.168.8.115:7077/final/#!");
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,100);wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='username-inputEl']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='username-inputEl']")).sendKeys("admin");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password-inputEl']")).sendKeys("admin");

Comment: driver.get("192.168.8.115:7077/final/#!") why you are not using http here

Comment: driver.get("http://192.168.8.115:7077/final/#!"); sorry copy paste mistake..  Note: This url will work only in our environment. Actually "http" is not pasting

Comment: Its working fine now, after changing the IE browser settings

Comment: You are not changing before, OK no issue. Please upvote and accept my answer if my answer helps you